# What protection does a face mask offer when using a resin printer?

Tags: safety

Printer manufacturers such as Elegoo ship their printers with masks and advice users to wear them when handling resin or unwashed prints.

In what way does the mask protect you?

For example, do the masks provide protection from inhaling toxic fumes, or are they primarily to prevent resin entering the mouth or nose?

Answer (score 2):

It depends entirely on what mask filter you use.

The classic FFP range only filter particulates, athough there are filters that will protect against gases too. You would have to find out what sort of fumes are released from the resin (if any) and specify a filter accordingly.

The image below shows the filter type and what it can filter.

[image: 1]

image link: https://www.bugoutbagbuilder.com/blog/best-gas-mask-filters-2019

Comment: Please [edit] your answer and add the source of the image, otherwise it could be considered plagiarism.

Comment: I'm exclusively referring to the ones that come in the box with the printers. They look like the ones that a dentist wears

Comment: @AaarghZombies If the mask is similar to a thin bit of fabric/material that just covers the nose and mouth then it almost certainly will not protect against fumes. It it probably just to stop the chemical entering the nose and mouth physically.